# make a join select using django orm

Tags: join, django-orm

```
create table topic (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL
) 

create table `subscribe` (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `topicid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   Foreign Key (topic_id) REFERENCES topic(id)
)
```

Now, given userid = "Amy01", I want to get all the topics that "Amy01" has subscribed.
when using SQL, it's:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.description
 from topic t join subscribe s on t.id = s.topicid
 where s.userid = "Amy01"
```

How can I get the same select using django orm ?

I already have a resolution, but I don't think it's pretty good:

```
searched_sub = FilterSubscribe.objects.filter(userid = "Amy01").select_related()
searched = []
for sub in searched_sub:
    searched.append(sub.topicid)
```

then, searched is all the topics that Amy01 has subscribed.

Is there any better statements to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution:

my_topic = Topic.objects.filter(Subscribe_set__userid = "Amy01").distinct()

"Subscribe_set" is used for 'callback' the subscribe table.

what's more, when define the Subscribe entity in models.py, if you code like this:

topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', related_name = '_subscribe'),

you can also achieve the select as:

my_topic = Topic.objects.filter(_subscribe__userid = "Amy01").distinct()

referenced to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects